Help to identify movie, where old man tells story of his life, that lasted more than average human life
Please, help me to identify a movie I watched a long time ago.  
I think it's American movie released in '90 or '00.   
Genres are drama, comedy.  
Language: English.  
Color, live action.  
There is a some pieces of plot, that I can remember.
Movie starts and end in the same place - nursing home or something like this. 
Two old men started a conversation inside building and then went to a terrace or veranda with a nice view: green lawn, blue sky. One of them lived enormous long for a human life. Maybe this man is and aging artifitial human. I'm not sure.  
So, the movie is a history of this man's life. But I don't remember any part of this story.
These men sat all day long there, teller continued his story. May be there was cut scenes that showed another people also gathered around and listened. 
Any ideas?

Since you mentioned artificial life, could it be Bicentennial Man?

The Green Mile (1999)

Your recount reminds me of The Green Mile, which is movie adaption of a Stephen King novel of the same name. The movie opens with an old man in a nursing home, and plays out through his narration of life as a prison guard in charge of "Death Row", which they referred to as the "Green Mile".
The movie stars Tom Hanks as the narrating prison guard, and Michael Clarke Duncan as one of the inmates, John Coffey. It also finishes back at the nursing home, where it is revealed that the narrator has led an unusually long life.

 It is revealed that John Coffey has the gift of supernatural healing. At one point, he grabs hold of the narrating character, and heals him of his bladder infection. It is later revealed that this healing has also gifted the narrator with an unnaturally long life, and at the time of his narration, he is 108 years of age. The movie ends on the character pondering how long he will live, considering that a mouse that was also healed through John Coffeys supernatural powers is still alive, over 60 years later.





You might be looking for the movie Mr. Nobody starring Jared Leto from 2009.
From Wikipedia:

The film tells the life story of Nemo Nobody, a 118-year-old man who is the last mortal on Earth after the human race has achieved quasi-immortality. Nemo, memory fading, refers to his three main loves and to his parents' divorce and subsequent hardships endured at three critical junctions in his life: at age nine, fifteen, and thirty-four.

Here is the trailer:




